# Chrome extension: get current tab url

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to get current tab url in Chrome extenstion.
All sources says that I need "chrome.tabs.query({active: true;})"
Truth is, that chrome.tabs.query can only be executed in background, and for background active tab is ALWAYS and ONLY "chrome://extensions".

Is there any way to get ACTUAL active tab's url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution.

As I previously mentioned, "chrome.tabs.query({active: true;})" can only run from background.js, and background.js's active tab is always browser's extensions page, so it's useless.

According to security policies we need instead to waste tons of PC's recources and do something like this:
in **client.js:**

```
function getcururl(){   

var s = document.createElement('script');
// TODO: add "script.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('gturl.js');
s.onload = function() {

    window.postMessage({ type: "gtcrurl", value: cururl }, "*");
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getcururl());
```

in **gturl.js:**

```
var cururl = window.location.host;
```

Now we can do in **popup.js** something like:

```
var crurl = "empty"; 
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
if(event.data.type === 'gtcrurl') {
    window._test = event.data.value;
    console.log(event.data.value);
    crurl = event.data.value;
}}, false);
```

Comment: i think thats not correct...i can perform a query in browser_action when "avtiveTab" permission is set... code is like:
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
 // get active tab url
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    var activeTabURL = activeTab.url;
    document.getElementById("input").value = activeTabURL;
  });